# ASUS Motherboard has a power switch issue

Tags: power, motherboard

I had a USB overcurrent issue and in the process of unplugging that I unplugged the he adapter for the turn on switch, since it was a usb in the front near the power button. I plugged that power back in but now the computer won't turn on when I push the switch. When I have the power plug plugged in, the motherboard is green! I really need help as this is a severe issue and it is a loaned computer. I checked the wires female side and the male parts of the motherboard, and nothing is missing or broken. It is an ASUS motherboard from 2014 o 2015.

Comment: Remove the CMOS battery and all power, then replace the battery.

Comment: did you plug the switch back in the correct place?